# Moduli of rank $1$ sheaves on surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface and $H$ be an ample divisor on $X$. Now consider $M_{X,H}(1, c_1,c_2)$ to be the moduli space of slope semistable (w.r. to $H$) rank $1$ torsion free sheaves with fixed Chern classes $c_1, c_2$. Then we know that $M_{X,H}(1, c_1,c_2) \cong \text{Pic}^{c_1}(X) \times \text{Hilb}^{c_2}(X)$, where $\text{Hilb}^{c_2}(X)$ is the Hilbert scheme of zero dimensional subschemes of length $c_2$ on $X$.

Is it true  that for a Hirzebruch surface $X$, one has $M_{X,H}(1, c_1,c_2) \cong \text{Hilb}^{c_2}(X)$?

Is it because for a Hirzebruch surface its irregularity $= h^1(\mathcal O_X)= \text{dim}(\text{Pic}^{c_1}(X))=0$? Please correct me if this is wrong.

Any suggestion/ remark is welcome.

Comment: Answers to both questions are yes.